# Is every locally compact Hausdorff space the union of countably many compact sets?

Tags: general-topology

I really only have been working with the real numbers which do have that property. So I was wondering if it generalizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  For instance, any discrete space is locally compact Hausdorff, but a compact subset of a discrete space must be finite, so an uncountable discrete space is not a countable union of compact sets.  A space which is a countable union of compact sets is called "$\sigma$-compact"; this is neither stronger nor weaker than local compactness.